# extending 2 bit bytearray to 4 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to decode some CAN messages into readable int's.
At the moment I'm getting byte arrays with values like this `bytearray(b'%\x19')`
What I'm trying to do next is to get a float of the byte array with this method
`return unpack_from('>f', data, 0)[0]`
my problem is that im getting a error like `struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 2)`

What is the best way to get the right buffer size? I know that 2bits can be converted into a float by using "e" instead of "f" but the values I'm getting are wrong.
I'm using the same method to get the values trough serial connection so I know it is possible.

Comment: Could you post what the desired output would be?

Comment: In this case it is about temperature, so it would be something like 21.48

Comment: This might be a coincidence but when you do `ord(b"%")` you get 37 and `ord(b"\x19")` gives 25, which combined would give 37.25. Could this be what you are looking for?

Comment: The problem is that I'm reading in data. So it needs to be more flexible. So i need to have a function that could handle something like ```ord(data)```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, you could expand this to support more decimals.

```
from struct import iter_unpack

data = bytearray(b'%\x19')
my_temp_iter = iter_unpack('>b', data) # you could name this my_temp to not pollute the namespace
my_temp = next(my_temp_iter)[0] + next(my_temp_iter)[0] / 100
print(my_temp) # prints 37.25
```

Alternitavely, if you know you have 2 bytes

```
my_temp = data[0] + data[1] / 100
print(my_temp) # prints 37.25
```

Comment: OK nvm, this doesn't work. data is not the same as the one I'm getting from the serial port. I think I need to get it to a float somehow

Comment: Maybe post more code? How do you get these values. It is very hard to get the values without knowing the encoding.

Comment: I found another way to do it, thanks for the help